# Syntax Required for If/Else Statement inside For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function that is applied onclick only when a specified variable is defined. Once that variable is defined, it loops through a set of nested arrays to produce a URL which the user is sent to. I added an else statement within the logic of the if statement so that if the condition is not met, the user is sent to a default URL which states, "sorry, no items found." However, since it is within a loop that is looping through items that don't match to find the one that does, it consistently applies the else statement before the loop finds the match.

Is there a better syntax to use?

```
function applyUrl() {

var locSelect = localStorage.getItem("loc");
var positSelect = localStorage.getItem("posit");
var userSelect = locSelect + " - " + positSelect;
if(localStorage.getItem("posit") != null){

        for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        var stuff = sortedArray[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < stuff.length; j++) {
            if(stuff[j] === userSelect) {
                  window.location.href = stuff[1];
                }else{
                  window.location.href = 'default.html';
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: move the conditional statement outside of the second loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to just store a variable outside your for loop then navigate to it after your done, also only keep looping if you dont have a `redirUrl` yet.

```
function applyUrl() {

    var locSelect = localStorage.getItem("loc");
    var positSelect = localStorage.getItem("posit");
    var userSelect = locSelect + " - " + positSelect;
    if (localStorage.getItem("posit") != null) {
        var redirUrl;    
        for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length && !redirUrl; i++) {
            var stuff = sortedArray[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < stuff.length && !redirUrl; j++) {
                if (stuff[j] === userSelect) {
                    redirUrl = stuff[1];
                }
            }
        }

        window.location.href = redirUrl || 'default.html';
    }
}
```

---

A nicer way to write this might be

```
function applyUrl() {
    var locSelect = localStorage.getItem("loc");
    var positSelect = localStorage.getItem("posit");
    var userSelect = locSelect + " - " + positSelect;
    if (positSelect != null) {
        // must have 2 elements and contain the user selection.
        var selArray = sortedArray.find(v=>v.length >= 2 && v.indexOf(userSelect) !== -1);
        if(selArray) {
            window.location.href = selArray[1];
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'default.html';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sir! This worked! Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

You should move the default redirect to outside the inner loop and only do it when at the end of the parent loop.

```
function applyUrl() {   
  var locSelect = localStorage.getItem("loc");
  var positSelect = localStorage.getItem("posit");
  var userSelect = locSelect + " - " + positSelect;

  if (localStorage.getItem("posit") != null) {      
    for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
      var stuff = sortedArray[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < stuff.length; j++) {
        if (stuff[j] === userSelect) {
          window.location.href = stuff[1];
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    window.location.href = 'default.html';          
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sir! I have been trying different else/if statements but didn't think to utilize the counter to equal the length to limit its involvement in the loop. I'll try it out! Thank you for the input!

Comment: @FredArnold I have edited it if first solution didn't help try this.

Comment: @YuriRamos Tweaked it slightly, realised you don't need the if condition at all. If it hasn't redirected at any point in the loops then I can make the assumption that we should redirect to default.

Comment: @Purgatory I tried both methods, and it still doesn't seem to direct to the right URLs.

Comment: Have you tried my third change as shown above, pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Yes, sir! It will only navigate to the default.html page. Ug's response above worked though!

Comment: Ah it must not be navigating away quick enough and continuing the script, i adjusted it so it returns on the inner loop, which would work the same as Ug's now. At least i tried.

Comment: The return way you have above worked as well! And I appreciate your efforts, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Because **window.location.href** redirects to another page you can change your code logic in this way:

```
for (var j = 0; j < stuff.length; j++) {
    if(stuff[j] === userSelect) {
        window.location.href = stuff[1];
    }
}
window.location.href = 'default.html';
```

In this way, if there is no match the outer redirect will be executed.